# Repeat loop in Scratch doesn't work for me

Tags: repeat, mit-scratch

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh6aZ.png)

I have a problem with repeat loop. If I write this code 10 times it works but, I face bugs when I use a repeat loop. Can someone help? Is there any settings which I need to change to use repeat loop. I saw from
a video, and everything works fine there.

I need help for repeat loop.

Comment: `Repeat` is not broken, _but_ by default, it has a built-in delay of 1/30 second per iteration, which may have its effect on race conditions in parts of your code you have not revealed. Read [this wiki article](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Repeat_()_(block)#Delays) to learn how to eliminate the delay.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from Ruud Helderman points out,the repeat loop in scratch has a 1/30 delay because it renders every action one by one,to avoid this,you need to create a custom block and tick the run without screen refresh,this will make it so that the screen only gets rendered after all of the actions are done and removes the delay.